# Help Center typo: "Again, explain why it should be re-openened."

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, help-center

The Help Center URL for reopening questions, [`/helpcenter/reopen-questions`](https://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/reopen-questions), has a typo:

> Again, explain why it should be **re-openened**.

should read:

> Again, explain why it should be re-opened.

or even:

> Again, explain why it should be reopened.

(On that note, "reopen" and "re-open" seem to have been used interchangeably throughout this text. I suggest sticking to one or the other.)

Comment: Openened is the new word. You haven't heard about the spellinging revolution?

Comment: @Undo:  You misspelled revolutionon.

Comment: You misspelleded misspelleded.

Comment: *everey worrd im thes possts iz misspelt*!

Comment: Stack Exchange 2: The Reopenening.

Comment: @voretaq7 ecxpect mizzplet?

Comment: This is really why the help center pages need to be community moderated. These things shouldn't need an entire post here whatsoever, it should just be in a queue somewhere.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII That wouldn't necessarily work very well - the help center is powered by "master" pages that are defined here on MSO and trickle down to other sites. The potential impact is huge and we don't really want them to be editable by a few folks here even with a review queue. Sure, the side-effect is that typos might take a bit longer to correct, but that's hardly a big deal.

Comment: @AnnaLear But the privilege wiki works the same way and we haven't seen a problem with that.

Comment: @Antony It takes a developer to push privilege wiki updates down to every site from MSO. That's not the case with the help center pages where edits take effect immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fixed.

I went with "reopen" as the canonical spelling, since that's what we use elsewhere in the UI (such as when voting to reopen a closed question).

Comment: Now if you could take that hyphen and put it in the `/helpcenter` path making it `/help-center`, that'd be great.